# how to run d3.js code in jsfiddle

Tags: d3.js, jsfiddle

how to run d3.js code in jsfiddle. I have created a fiddle but its not working:

here's the link : 
https://jsfiddle.net/rajatmehta/tm5166e1/7/

```
var GenData = function(N, lastTime) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    output.push({
      value: Math.random() * 10,
      timestamp: lastTime
    });
    lastTime = lastTime + 1000;
  }

  return output;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point at the https url - https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js instead of http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

https://jsfiddle.net/csz8fje5/1/

```
links to jsfiddle must include code...
```